# Exibir tela de dialogo para fazer o download com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um projeto em MVC onde tem um botão que faz o **download** de arquivos porém ao clicar no botão é aberto uma **nova guia** no navegador e os arquivos são baixados automaticamente, como nos exemplos demonstrados nesse link:

[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp](http://Window%20open()%20Method)

O meu código funciona perfeitamente: 
var url = "http://10.155.XXX.XXX/site_do_fornecedor/arquivo_para_download.aspx?id="
window.open(url + 10 + '10/12/2019', "_blank", "width=200, height=100");

Porém gostaria que fosse exibida a tela de `diálogo` onde o usuário decida em que diretório salvar os arquivos.

**Exemplo**

Quando clico no botão **download** é executado o código javascript descrito anteriormente e a uma janela do chrome é aberta: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço pra essa janela do navegador não ser exibida ?

Implementei a sugestão muito interessante do [Daniel Mendes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/88014/daniel-mendes):

```
function downloadMP3(_url, _strArrId, _data) {

    fetch(_url + _strArrId + "&Date=09/12/2019")
        .then(data => {
            data.blob()
                .then(blob => {
                    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    const link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.href = url;
                    link.download = url;
                    link.click();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Porém foi exibida a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que vejo a URL de destino tem que habilitar o [CORS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) é isso mesmo ?

Comment: Por código puro acho que não é possível exibir o diálogo de salvar como. A única maneira que vejo é se o usuário instalar uma extensão no navegador que permita o código chamar o diálogo através da API [downloads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

Hard,

Se você se refere a dialog do navegador que permite escolher onde salvar o arquivo, isso é uma opção do próprio navegador, onde existe uma configuração que o navegador efetua o donwload de forma automática, sem exibir a dialog e salvando na pasta definida também nas configurações do mesmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Existe a possibilidade de você criar a sua dialog de confirmação, porém com isso, o usuário pode acabar tendo que confirmar duas vezes e você não consegue interferir no local onde o arquivo será salvo.

Para essa confirmação, o próprio javascript já tem métodos para isso:

```js
confirm("Efetuar o download?");
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/window/confirm

---

Agora caso o problema seja a sua própria dialog criada pelo `window.open`, você pode refatorar o código, removendo a sua dialog e criando por exemplo uma tag `<a>` temporária e efetuar o click na mesma, veja um exemplo abaixo:

```js
function download() {
  fetch("https://developer.mozilla.org/static/img/embed/promos/devedition-logo.63846dba2e2f.png")
  .then(data => {
    data.blob()
    .then(blob => {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement("a");

      link.href = url;
      link.download = "63846dba2e2f.png";

      link.click();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="download()">Fazer download</button>
```

Comment: Olá @Daniel Mendes obrigado pela sua colaboração, mas não é bem essa minha dúvida. Eu atualizei o meu post e adicionei uma imagem.

Comment: veja que quando eu clico no botão Download é executado um javascript direcionando pra uma URL e uma janela do navegador é aberta.

Comment: @hard123 criei um exemplo de download com javascript sem utilizar a window.open, espero que lhe ajude.

Comment: Obrigado! @Daniel Mendes vou implementar e depois dou um retorno aqui sobre o resultado !

Comment: implementei a sua sugestão e pelo erro retornado falta habilitar o [CORS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: Isso realmente precisa ser visto, você precisa ver se precisa enviar algum header também etc.